# how to access an element's data inside its own event handler using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to retrieve an `data` attribute of a button inside it's own event handler. I have tried the following `jQuery` code for the HTML at the end. But the button doesn't seem to respond as I expected:

```
$('btn.btn-add-layer').on('click', function() {
  var layertype = $(this).data('layertype');
  alert('type : ' + layertype);
});
```

Can someone please help explain how to fix the above so that the button can tell its `data`?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<button data-layertype="base" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-add-layer">OK</button>
```

-- EDIT --

Thanks everyone who have helped. As I suspected and pointed out in the two answers, it's a typo. I was thinking about `button.btn-...` but wrote `btn.btn-...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must select the button with button.btn-add-layer your code must be like:

```
 $('button.btn-add-layer').on('click', function() {
  var layertype = $(this).data('layertype');
  alert('type : ' + layertype);
 });
```

more about jquery button selector from [here](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn.btn-add-layer').on('click', function() {
  var layertype = $(this).data('layertype');
  alert('type : ' + layertype);
});
```

Your selector was a bit messed up!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, the [fastest](http://jsperf.com/dataset-vs-jquery-data) is this:

```
$('.btn.btn-add-layer').on('click', function() {
  var layertype = this.getAttribute("data-layertype");
  alert('type : ' + layertype);
});
```

You also have an error in your selector, try `$('button.btn.btn-add-layer')` instead.